# New Install Dual Boot, Win11 Boot failure

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

New Ubuntu 23.10 install, to spare partion space, dual boot Win11 existing install, default values throughout. HP Prodesk.

Install all looked fine until final reboot 'remove boot media' where I got a loop with a 'system fail' or similar.. Going to advanced repair gave me the bootloader options and ubuntu boots and power cycles.

Selecting the windows partition however errors out with:

```
error: malformed EFI Device Path has length=0
```

I now have ubuntu running but need win 11 dual boot.

EDIT for more info.

The Windows data is visible on dev/nvme0n1p3 the boot fail is pointing to dev/nvme0n1p2 (if memory serves without doing another reboot) which I am assuming is the boot partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)